# Curve fit in MATLAB like 1+x/1+x^2

Tags: matlab, curve-fitting, data-fitting

I have a bunch of data that I want to fit to a function:

[image]

All variables except `x` must be fit. Can you help me with this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [curve-fitting by optimization](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/math/example-curve-fitting-via-optimization.html) to find parameters `a`, `b`, `w`, and `x_c`:

Create an objective function, `sseval()`, that contains the function you want to fit to as the target:

```
function sse = sseval(para, xdata, ydata)
    % Set up the function parameters:
    a = para(1);
    b = para(2);
    w = para(3);
    x_c = para(4);

    % Compute the target function (what you want to fit to):
    funct = (b*(w/2)^2 - a*(w/2)*(xdata - x_c)) ./ ((xdata - x_c).^2 + (w/2)^2).^2;

    % Return the sum of squared errors for the given set of data:
    sse = sum((ydata - funct).^2);
end
```

Then use [`fminsearch()`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fminsearch.html) to find your parameters:

```
% Start off with a random set of parameters:
para0 = rand(4, 1);

% Create a handle to function 'sseval()' ('xdata' and 'ydata' correspond to
% variable 'x' and the data that you want to fit to the function, respectively):
funct = @(para)sseval(para, xdata, ydata);

% Find the best parameters that fit the target function:
best_para = fminsearch(funct, para0);
```

---

To see how well the parameters were fit, you can plot the fitted curve on top of the data:

```
% Set up the function parameters:
a = best_para(1);
b = best_para(2);
w = best_para(3);
x_c = best_para(4);

% Compute the target function using the fitted parameters:
yfit = (b*(w/2)^2 - a*(w/2)*(xdata - x_c)) ./ ((xdata - x_c).^2 + (w/2)^2).^2;

% Plot the data along with the fitted curve:
plot(xdata, ydata, '*');
hold on
plot(xdata, yfit, 'r');
xlabel('xdata')
ylabel('Data and Fitted Curve')
title('Data and Best Fitting Curve')
legend('Data', 'Fitted Curve')
hold off
```